# Statistics - Covariance and variance question

Tags: statistics, regression, economics

Please fill in the intermediate steps
$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i(x_i-\bar x)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2$$
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i(y_i-\bar y)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the fact that $\bar{x}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})=0$.